# Resetting the dongle serial ports

Tags: linux, serial-port, at-command, modem, lte

I want to do reconnect - i.e Once pdp session is established with modem using sequence of AT commands (like AT+CGATT,ATDT etc), I am trying to reestablish the connection after disconnecting .So I just want to reset ATDT port and resend the command .. Approach of Closing and opening port is working effectively -but very few times its failing (ATDT command was sent successfully but response was not received)
I am trying to reset the port of modem by this method

```
//close port
 {
if(fdDataPort != -1)
    {
    MSG_NOTICE("Closing AT[Data] port %d",fdDataPort);
    close (fdDataPort);
        MSG_NOTICE("Closed AT[Data] port",NULL);
        fdDataPort= -1;
    }
}
```

//open port

```
{
struct termios tio;
    memset(&tio, 0, sizeof(termios));

    if ((fdDataPort = open("/dev/ttyUSB2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY| O_SYNC | O_NONBLOCK )) != -1)
    {
        cfmakeraw (&tio);

        tio.c_iflag = 0;//IGNCR;
        tio.c_cflag |= CLOCAL | CREAD;
        usleep(200000);
        tcflush(fdDataPort, TCIOFLUSH);
        tcsetattr(fdDataPort, TCSANOW, &tio);
        tcflush(fdDataPort, TCIOFLUSH);
        tcflush(fdDataPort, TCIOFLUSH);
        cfsetospeed(&tio, B115200);
        cfsetispeed(&tio, B115200);
        tcsetattr(fdDataPort, TCSANOW, &tio);

        usleep(200000);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to reset the ttyUSB?
Or is there any other approach to reset the serial port of modem ,Like sending some AT command Or changing some configuration

Once i close and open the port .i tried sending ATZ to reset configuration ,but response is not received . Not even ERROR . Does this mean port not closed properly ? I am stuck .please help

Comment: A close port or open port does not reset a local or remote device.  A reset initiated by software is typically device dependent, and when available, typically only performed on system startup by the device driver.  BTW your use of termios is quite flawed, and the `usleep()`s are ineffective.  If the modem you want to reset  is on the remote end of the serial link, then the only possible method would be an AT command.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply .I tried sending ATZ command .But its not quite effective. Please suggest if any other AT Command/method is available for smooth reset

Comment: ATZ is supposed to reset the configuration, not the modem hardware.  What are you actually trying to accomplish/solve?  Is this an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: Actually i want to do reconnect - i.e Once pdp session is established with modem using sequence of AT commands (like AT+CGATT,ATDT etc), I am trying to reestablish the connection after disconnecting .So I just want to reset ATDT port and resend the command .. Approach of Closing and opening port is working effectively -but very few times its failing (ATDT command was sent successfully but response not received)